# Can we use a nested class for IBDesignable?

Tags: ios, swift, inner-classes, ibdesignable

I am developing a graphic library in Swift. The code cannot be shared, but I made a sample [here](https://github.com/csarkis/TestIBDesignablesPod/) (see the button example, Radio buttons were dedicated to another question).

I would like to have a namespace `MyGraphicLibrary` for my components: `MyGraphicLibrary.Button` instead of `MyGraphicLibraryButton`

The sample pod has two classes:

```
// Independent class
@IBDesignable public class CustomButton: UIButton {
    ...
}

// Namespace for my components
public class MyGraphicLibrary: NSObject {

}

// Namespaced button
public extension MyGraphicLibrary {
    @objc(MyGraphicLibraryButton) @IBDesignable class Button: UIButton {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `CustomButton` class is behaving as expected in the interface builder: I can easily add the custom class to the button (see `Main.storyboard`).

[image: Non-nested custom button class]

For the nested class, it is not possible to set it with its normal name (`Button` or `MyGraphicLibrary.Button`).

The only way is to set the class @objc name `MyGraphicLibraryButton`; there is no autocompletion and the module must be set to `none` (which looks like a nonsense, the class belongs to the GraphicLibrary module). Removing the @objc name makes no difference.

[image: Nested custom button class]

Is there a way to make the nested class be handled correctly by the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1):

I think, in general, the answer to your question is "No" you cannot use Objective-C classes in the way you are trying to.

Interface Builder is looking for an Objective-C Class name in it's interface. Objective-C presents a flat space for class names.  There is no concept of a nested namespace (which is why you end up with name prefixes like 'NS')

You are trying to impose a namespace structure using features of Swift, but that structure has no meaning to Objective-C.  Even if you declare an Objective-C class in a nested Swift context, its still going to exist in the flat space of Objective-C classes.

And Interface Builder is going to pull the name from that flat space.

Comment: I get it, that is exactly the goal of the prefixed objc name.
But why can't I have this class in the dropdown list? And why can I add the class only with "module" set to "none" ?

Comment: Mostly because what you are doing is unusual and it appears to be confusing Interface Builder.   If you want the behavior supported then I would contact Apple through their Feedback mechanism and describe how you would prefer this behaves.